# RabbitMQ: server side Calculation for every received Message

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I'm working with RabbitMQ and I want on the server side to conduct a calculation each time an Exchange receives a message.

I have a queue for ratings and when too many bad reviews (let's say more than ten) received, then a consumer should be notified.

What options are there for serverside logic ? 
I've been reading about Spring RabbitMQ, but am not sure ?

Comment: Server Side: The side on which also runs RabbitMQ,
Calculation:
I have a queue for ratings and when too many bad reviews (let's say more than ten) received, then a consumer should be notified.

Comment: Thanks IMSoP,
The first proposal sounds good for my use case.
My focus is on Java. So I'll probably use Spring, or is there an alternative?
Can the consumer of this job run on the same host as RabbitMQ broker, or is this bad design ?

Comment: I've put my comments into an answer, and edited some of yours into the question itself, as long threads of comments are discouraged here. Hope it's of some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't really a "server side" with a message-based system; rather, the RabbitMQ service sits somewhere and relays messages to and from any number of producers and consumers. Depending on the hardware you have available, and the amount of processing being performed, these could all be on the same server, or you could have resources dedicated to each task.

Calculations based on the content of messages is the job of consumers, which can be written in any language you feel comfortable writing them in, as long as you use a serialization of the message that all can understand (e.g. JSON, XML). For a simple counter, you may not need much framework to extract the data you need.

Any number of Queues can receive copies of messages from the same Exchange, so you can either pick up all messages from the exchange and count only the bad reviews, or you can put the rating into the "routing key" and use a "topic exchange" to pre-filter them.

After that, you could use a simple memory store like Redis to store a counter, and when it reaches the limit, either act on it within that consumer, or publish a message to a new exchange for processing by a different consumer.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation IMSoP,
helps me a lot :)

Comment: @Jon555Nose Glad to hear it. If you click the tickmark next to the answer, the question will be marked as "solved" for other readers.